# JCarousel - Items added with add() do not respond to .click()

Tags: jquery, addition, dynamic, jcarousel

I am loading items to a carousel (based on another carousel click event) using something like this:

```
    testCarousel.stopAuto();
testCarousel.reset();
testCarousel.add(0,"<LI>TEST</LI>");
testCarousel.add(1,"<LI>TEST2</LI>");
testCarousel.size(2);
```

The items are displayed properly. but the testCarousel onclick event on the `<li>`'s never gets called! On the other hand, if I'm adding the items using static html `<li>`, the click event DOES get called.

Heres an example of the click function:

```
$("#test-carousel li").click(function () {
alert("CLICKED!");
```

});

Is there some function I have to call to make the `<li>` items added to the carousel using add() launch the click event when clicked? Or maybe it should be handled differently ?

All needed items are on the form, no ajax calls.

I searched everywhere but no example or solution for my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#test-carousel li").live('click',function () {
    alert("CLICKED!");      
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/